# Select a region on the graph in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to use a graph on a canvas in tkinter, so I used matplotlib library (matplotlib.backends.tkagg and matplotlib.backends.backend_agg). Now, I want to select a region on the graph by creating a square using my mouse. In an empty canvas it’s possible, but unfortunately, there's no accessor for the pointer to the native renderer of tkagg graph.

Any idea about selecting a region on the graph in matplotlib/tkinter by creating a square using a mouse?

Comment: This is rather hard to understand and most probably too broad to be answered. Hence just a general hint: have you looked at [`RectangleSelector`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/rectangle_selector.html)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is thing I am looking for, rectangle selector. But the file in the page of  https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/rectangle_selector.html doesn't work. I tried .ipynb file in Jupyter and .py file in Spyder, results are the same: you can see the graph, but rectangle selector doesn't work.

Comment: It will of course not work with png images, but only with interactive figures.

Comment: What I want to say is depended files as .ipynb or .py don't work. Maybe work in Tkinter GUI?

Comment: Download the `rectangle_selector.py` file to your disc, then run `python rectangle_selector.py`. Does this not work?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: What happens when you try it? Is there an error?

Comment: Only you can see the graph, no error mesage. If you click on the graph and drag, no reaction.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using (`print(matplotlib.__version__)`), and which backend (`print(plt.get_backend())`)? Also a screenshot of how it looks may help here.

Comment: print(matplotlib.__version__) : response was 2.1.2, after uptading now "3.0.0", print(plt.get_backend()) : response is "module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline".

Comment: I see. The above "run `python rectangle_selector.py`" is meant literally. You open up a system bash, you cd to the directory where your file lives, you type `python rectangle_selector.py` and hit Enter. If you run this as script as suggested, you cannot get `backend_inline` as backend - that would only happen inside an IPython environment.